# lein deps fails with cljfx

Tags: javafx, leiningen, openbsd, cljfx

I am trying to use [cljfx](https://github.com/cljfx/cljfx). However, lein deps fails and I got a bit stuck...

the error I get is

```
Could not find artifact org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:${javafx.platform}:19.0.2.1
in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
Could not find artifact org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:${javafx.platform}:19.0.2.1
in clojars (https://repo.clojars.org/)
Could not find artifact org.openjfx:javafx-base:jar:${javafx.platform}:19.0.2.1 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
Could not find artifact org.openjfx:javafx-base:jar:${javafx.platform}:19.0.2.1 in clojars (https://repo.clojars.org/)
Could not find artifact org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:jar:${javafx.platform}:19.0.2.1
in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
Could not find artifact org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:jar:${javafx.platform}:19.0.2.1
in clojars (https://repo.clojars.org/)
Could not find artifact org.openjfx:javafx-media:jar:${javafx.platform}:19.0.2.1 in
central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
Could not find artifact org.openjfx:javafx-media:jar:${javafx.platform}:19.0.2.1 in
clojars (https://repo.clojars.org/)
Could not find artifact org.openjfx:javafx-web:jar:${javafx.platform}:19.0.2.1 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
Could not find artifact org.openjfx:javafx-web:jar:${javafx.platform}:19.0.2.1 in clojars (https://repo.clojars.org/)
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies, file system permissions, or network issues.
```

I tried to change cljfx version with no success.

versions:

```bash
lein --version
Leiningen 2.9.10 on Java 11.0.18 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
```

project.clj file

```clj
(defproject ui "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "EPL-2.0 OR GPL-2.0-or-later WITH Classpath-exception-2.0"
            :url "https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0/"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.11.1"]
                 [cljfx "1.7.24"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot ui.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all
                       :jvm-opts ["-Dclojure.compiler.direct-linking=true"]}})
```

OS

```
~> uname -a
OpenBSD my.machine 7.3 GENERIC.MP#3 amd64
```

Any clues on how to solve is really appreciated